# make a list with 2 value of 2 columns depending another column

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I would like to create a list based on the value of a column, the value here is "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes". And in this list put the 2 values ​​latitude and longitude for this region.

My data frame :

[image]

I want to make a list like this :
listeNom_Région = [[46.153426, 4.926114],[46.009188,5.428017]...[45.749499,5.594320]]

Answer (score 1):

```py
liste_norm = list(zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude']))
```

This will create tuples instead of lists inside your list. However, tuples function very similar to list. If you really want lists, you can iterate over the result and change them like this:

```py
liste_norm = [list(elem) for elem in liste_norm]
```